# Intellij Idea 12 gradle build

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I am trying to build a project with gradle from within Intellij Idea 12 (commercial editon) but this keeps failing. I have the **gradle plugin** enabled and also the **gradle gui** plugin. The native project gradle import is working. (I'm not using `gradle idea` btw.)

When using the *bash* I only run `gradle war` to build my web application. Now I want to do the same from within Intellij.

The **gradle gui** plugin seems to be using the wrong JDK (I guess it's the one Idea uses, a 1.6 JDK) and therefor fails to compile because this is a JDK 1.7 project. And it doesn't integrate well into Idea because it seems like an external build process (like triggering external ant tasks).

What I have done so far is to configure my own **artifact** in a way that is equivalent to the one `gradle war` would have build. But that means a lot of configuration and simply feels wrong. There should be a better way?

So what do I have to do to make Idea compile a project in a way similar to the command line gradle task?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JetGradle plugin doesn't provide native tasks support at the moment. It's scheduled for v.12.1 - [IDEA-95897](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-95897). Feel free to track the [plugin's news](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/News) and [update it manually](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Gradle+integration#Gradleintegration-Preassembledset%28applicablefortheIJv.12%29) as soon as corresponding support is provided.

Comment: This sounds like a nice improvement. Thanks for sharing the link to that issue! Is there already a release date for version 12.1 announced?